# How to make Range_Seek_bar move in steps (not smooth)

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I try this library :https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar
with the repository : 
compile 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'

and i need to make the seek bar move in steps
the library doesn't support steps movement 
is there solution, or other libs for this issue

this is the lib xml :

```
 <com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/well_range"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        rsb:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"

                        rsb:activeColor="#a96b21"
                        rsb:absoluteMinValue="0"
                        rsb:absoluteMaxValue="10"
                        rsb:alwaysActive="true"
                        rsb:showLabels="false"
                        rsb:barHeight="4dp"
                        rsb:defaultColor="#efefef"
                        rsb:thumbDisabled="@mipmap/range_seek_bubble_brown"
                        rsb:thumbNormal="@mipmap/range_seek_bubble_brown"
                        rsb:thumbPressed="@mipmap/range_seek_bubble_brown"
                        rsb:valuesAboveThumbs="false" />
```

[image]

Comment: You could : 1. Modify the library. After all, it's open source. 2. Look for another library yourself using a search engine. As it stands, your question is either too broad or off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [This Library](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar) or [This one](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar) can help solve your problem.

I remember using the first library and it has the method to handle progress.For eg:-

```
seek_time.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new OnRangeBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onIndexChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftThumbIndex,
                    int rightThumbIndex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        });
```

Comment: i try them , not working. no cannot deal with progress value

Comment: there is no option to deal with progress value like the default seek bar : like  @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
      boolean fromUser) {
     
    }

Comment: @WaelAbo-Aishah check new answer and it has methods that you require.just check the sample it has everything.but you need to analyse everything.